# where to modify set_language method in django

Tags: django, translation

I read this question [Django 1.8 set_language view does not redirect to specified language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31306277/django-1-8-set-language-view-does-not-redirect-to-specified-language/55123284#55123284) and its answers, but I want to know where should I modify the set_language method, how can I access to the set_language view?

Comment: What modifications do you want to make?

Comment: One of the answers to the link below was this one https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24122, I want to have it in my project, but I don't know where to put that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can access by importing `from django.views.i18n import set_language`

Comment: Where do I import it (from django.views.i18n import set_language) @YugandharChaudhari?